# Not able to display an activity indicator on top of a static tableview

Tags: ios, swift, uiactivityviewcontroller, uiactivityindicatorview

I'm not able to display an activity indicator on top a static table view though I wrote the below code in viewDidLoad.

```
let activityIndicatorView = UIActivityIndicatorView(activityIndicatorStyle: UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.gray)
tableView.backgroundView = activityIndicatorView
tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyle.none
self.activityIndicatorView = activityIndicatorView
self.activityIndicatorView.isHidden = false
self.tableView.addSubview(activityIndicatorView)
self.activityIndicatorView.startAnimating()
```

Comment: Do you mean PullToRefresh in TableView???

Comment: If you want to do pull to refresh then simply use the refresh control

Comment: If you want table header then initiate it as a table view header not as a subview and use UIRefreshControl if you want pull to refresh.

Comment: where you are adding this code ?

Comment: i want the activity indicator as soon as the view is brought onto the screen.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of adding `UIActivityIndicatorView` in `tableView`, add it to inside your main view and call the `bringSubview(toFront:)` on the main view to to bring the `indicatorView` to front and you have't set the origin position for your `indicatorView` set that also.

```
self.activityIndicatorView = UIActivityIndicatorView(activityIndicatorStyle: UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.gray)
tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyle.none
self.activityIndicatorView.isHidden = false

//Add inside your view
self.view.addSubview(activityIndicatorView)

//Set activityIndicatorView origin in the screen
self.activityIndicatorView.center = self.view.center

//Try to bring activityIndicatorView to front
self.view.bringSubview(toFront: activityIndicatorView)

self.activityIndicatorView.startAnimating()
```

Comment: is it self.view or self.tableView ? @Nirav D

Comment: @RohitDulam I'm saying is use `self.view` instead of `self.tableView` to add activityIndicator.

Comment: Sorry i dint look at it properly. @Nirav D

Comment: @RohitDulam Do like my edited answer and don't set `activityIndicatorView` as `backgroundView` for `tableView`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but it doesn't seem to solve my problem. @Nirav D

Comment: @RohitDulam Have you remove that line where you are setting `activityIndicatorView` as `tableView`'s `backgroundView`, check once again my edited answer.

Comment: @RohitDulam The issue is probably that you haven't set origin for ` `activityIndicatorView` set that also like I have done in my latest edited answer.

Comment: @RohitDulam Have you try setting center for `activityIndicatorView`, is it working now?

Answer (score 0):

You cant add subview to tableview, Try adding it on Navigation controllers view instead.

like :

```
self.view.superviewaddSubview(activityIndicatorView);
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but it hasn't solved my problem. @Ninja Hattori

Answer (score 0):

If you use pull to refresh then implement this code:

```
  var refreshControl: UIRefreshControl!

override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()

   refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()

   refreshControl.addTarget(self, action: "refresh:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)
   tableView.addSubview(refreshControl) 
}

func refresh(sender:AnyObject) {
   tableView.reloadData()
   refreshControl.endRefreshing()  
}
```

Comment: check editable code in swift, i think this will help you.

Comment: I don't want to pull to refresh. Basically i'm trying to populate the tableview with the data I get from the server, so as soon as the view controller is opened i want the activity indicator to kick in until the whole table view is populated and the cells are properly resized.